# How to get the latest number using LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, linq

Here lists a payment history of a customer in a db table

```
CustomerId  PayId   FeePaid
xx-yy-zz    37      0
xx-yy-zz    32      0
xx-yy-zz    31      30.00
xx-yy-zz    28      0
xx-yy-zz    26      0
xx-yy-zz    18      35.99
xx-yy-zz    17      0
xx-yy-zz    16      0
xx-yy-zz    9       12.00
xx-yy-zz    6       0
```

The PaymentId column is auto incremented.
How to get the last payment of this customer, i.e., the number $30.00?
My project is Asp.net API, so I need use LINQ to get the number.

Comment: define "latest"; is the `PayId` a monotonically incrementing number (auto-generated doesn't automatically mean "monotonically incrementing"); why isn't the answer `0`? are we excluding zeros?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we assume that we're ignoring zeros, and that `PayId` is monotonically incrementing, then presumably:

as LINQ:

```cs
var val = ctx.SomeTable
    .Where(x => x.CustomerId == customerId && x.FeePaid != 0)
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.PayId)
    .Select(x => x.FeePaid)
    .First();
```

or as SQL:

```sql
select top 1 FeePaid
from SomeTable
where CustomerId = @customerId
and FeePaid <> 0
order by PayId desc
```

Comment: It seems `&& x.FeePaid != 0` check may not necessary.

Comment: @Batuhan why? OP says the answer should be 30.00; without that, the answer would be 0.0

Answer (score 0):

Try this linq expression:

```
var result = await (from d in _ctx.MyTable
                    where d.CustomerId="xx-yy-zz" && d.FreePaid > 0
                    orderby d.PayId descending
                    select d.FreePaid).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

- tried to avoid negative queries
- awaitable function

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

> The PaymentId column is auto incremented

My advice would be to group the `PaymentHistories` per user, so by common value of CustomerId.

Then for each group, keep the `PaymentHistory` that has the highest value of `PaymentId`. After all: `PaymentId` is auto-increments, so the `PaymentHistory` in the group of `PaymentHistories` of Customer X is the one with the highest PaymentId

For this I used the overload of [Queryable.GroupBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.groupby?view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Queryable_GroupBy__4_System_Linq_IQueryable___0__System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Func___0___1___System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Func___0___2___System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Func___1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___2____3___) that has a parameter resultSelector, so I can precisely specify what I want in my result.

```
IQueryable<PaymentHistory> paymentHistories = ...
var lastCustomerPayments = paymentHistories.GroupBy(

    // parameter keySelector: make groups with same CustomerId
    paymentHistory => paymentHistory.CustomerId,

    // parameter resultSelector: for every CustomerId and all PaymentHistories
    // that have this value for CustomerId, make one new:
    (customerId, paymentHistoriesWithThisCustomerId) => new
    {
        CustomerId = customerId,

        // get the feePaid of the PaymentHistory with the largest PaymentId
        FeePaid = paymentHistoriesWithThisCustomerId
            .OrderByDescending(paymentHistory => paymentHistory.PaymentId)
            .Select(paymentHistory => paymentHistory.FeePaid)
            .FirstOrDefault(),
    }
```

If you don't want FeePaid, but also the PaymentId, use the following resultSelector:

```
(customerId, paymentHistoriesWithThisCustomerId) => new
{
    CustomerId = customerId,

    LastPayment = paymentHistoriesWithThisCustomerId
        .OrderByDescending(paymentHistory => paymentHistory.PaymentId)
        .Select(paymentHistory => new
        {
            PaymentId = paymentHistory.PaymentId,
            FeePaid = paymentHistory.FeePaid,
        })
        .FirstOrDefault();
    }
```